# Randomizar imagens como texturas em solidos 3D

Tags: c++, random, java-processing

Boas, eu tenho 30 sólidos e tenho uma imagem diferente para cada um deles. Eu criei um *array* para as imagens, e se escolher usar a mesma imagem em todos (como deixei aqui no codigo, usa a `bandeira [0]`) ele corre e está tudo bem!

Eu agora quero fazer um *random* que percorre o *array* das imagens e que atribui uma imagem diferente a cada um dos sólidos, mas por algum motivo quando tentei fazer `(int index = int(random(0, bandeira.length));` - e ficar com o `index` no lugar do `[0]`) ele continua a criar os sólidos todos com a mesma imagem.

MAIN

```
int numPaises = 30;

float theta = 0;
PImage logo, chao;
PShape pessoa;

Paises [] solidos = new Paises [numPaises];  //Array solidos!

PImage[] bandeira = new PImage[30];


void setup() {

  bandeira[0] = loadImage("portugal.jpg");
  bandeira[1] = loadImage("espanha.jpg");
  bandeira[2] = loadImage("franca.jpg");
  bandeira[3] = loadImage("italia.jpg");
  bandeira[4] = loadImage("inglaterra.jpg");
  bandeira[5] = loadImage("alemanha.jpg");
  bandeira[6] = loadImage("brasil.jpg");
  bandeira[7] = loadImage("estadosUnidos.jpg");
  bandeira[8] = loadImage("china.jpg");
  bandeira[9] = loadImage("russia.jpg");
  bandeira[10] = loadImage("quenia.jpg");
  bandeira[11] = loadImage("argelia.jpg");
  bandeira[12] = loadImage("africaSul.jpg");
  bandeira[13] = loadImage("armenia.jpg");
  bandeira[14] = loadImage("austria.jpg");
  bandeira[15] = loadImage("bahamas.jpg");
  bandeira[16] = loadImage("belgica.jpg");
  bandeira[17] = loadImage("benin.jpg");
  bandeira[18] = loadImage("bulgaria.jpg");
  bandeira[19] = loadImage("chile.jpg");
  bandeira[20] = loadImage("congo.jpg");
  bandeira[21] = loadImage("cuba.jpg");
  bandeira[22] = loadImage("filandia.jpg");
  bandeira[23] = loadImage("jamaica.jpg");
  bandeira[24] = loadImage("noruega.jpg");

  size (1200, 650, P3D);

  for (int j=0; j < solidos.length; j++) {
    float angle = j * TWO_PI / numPaises;
    float x = 0 + 2000 * cos(angle);  
    float z = 0 + 2000 * sin(angle);
    int index = int(random(0, bandeira.length));     // *******
    solidos[j] = new Paises(x, 700, z, bandeira[0]);
  }
}

void draw() {

  background (0);

  scale(0.8); //escala de visão
  translate(700, 0, -3500);

  for (int j =0; j < solidos.length; j++) {
    solidos[j].render();
  }

  theta += 0.020;
}
```

CLASS PAISES

```
class Paises {
  float x, y, z;
  float w, h, d;

  //CONSTRUTOR

  Paises(float nx, float ny, float nz, PImage img ) {
    x =nx;
    y = ny;
    z =nz;
    w= random(130, 200);
    h= random(400, 500);
    d= random(130, 200);

    noStroke();

    pessoa = createShape(BOX, w, h, d);
    pessoa.setTexture(img);
  }

  void render() {
    pushMatrix();
    rotateY(theta);
    translate(x, y-h/2, z);
    shape(pessoa);
    //box(w, h, d);
    popMatrix();
  }
}
```

Comment: Não deveria ser `solidos[j] = new Paises(x, 700, z, bandeira[index]);`?

Comment: isso foi o que eu tentei, só deixei o [0], para dizer que se escolher 1 em especifico ele funciona correctamente com todas elas, fica evidentemente e sempre com a mesma imagem em todos os solidos, que não é o que eu quero.

Comment: experimente declarar "pessoa" no escopo da classe, pode ser que vc esteja reescrevendo em cima do mesmo objeto (aí ficaria só a ultima bandeira). Aproveite pra [edit] a questão e colocar tags mais relevantes da linguagem.

Comment: Muito obrigado, já está a funcionar correctamente :)

Comment: qual foi a solução? Você pode usar o campo abaixo para postar como resposta, se quiser.

Comment: estava mesmo a ficar com a ultima bandeira! mais uma vez obrigado :)

Answer (score 2):

O problema é que da maneira que `pessoa` tinha sido declarada, a classe estava sobreescrevendo seu valor a cada instância.

Já está a funcionar correctamente, bastou mover a declaração de `pessoa` para dentro classe:

```
class Paises {

  PShape pessoa;
  float x, y, z;
  float w, h, d;
```

no `setup()` fica assim:

```
int index = int(random(0, bandeira.length));     
solidos[j] = new Paises(x, 700, z, bandeira[index]);
```

Comment: fiz um leve ajuste na resposta, se achar que não ficou bom, você pode [edit] novamente, ou reverter para sua versão anterior neste link: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/135240/revisions

Comment: sem problema :)